# Should I have a foreign key of product in a table of items of a buy?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let me explain; I've got two tables:

```
# tb_buy

buy_id
address_id
buy_value

# tb_buy_items

product_id - foreign key of a product table
buy_id
```

It's only an example, but is it recommended to use a structure like this?

Or should I put info about the product in `tb_buy_items`? Like name, cod, value, because if someone deletes this product, the line will be removed or it will set the foreign key to NULL and no-one will know that product was purchased...?

I would like some hints about this, thanks.

Comment: To avoid the situation you mention at the end, information that is likely to change such as the product price etc should be saved alongside the order/"buy" at the time it's created as a hard reference.

Comment: i got same situation on delivery address 'address_id' is a foreign key of address table but if the user change something after or remove this address, maybe i shouldn't use the foreign key of address_id here and only use user_id foreign key and put the address in a normal field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ¨buy¨ table is for historical purpose (to hold the order history) I would just make a copy of all information that I would like to keep (code, name, price at that the purchased moment etc). just as you said, a change of product will affect all. but if it´s for ¨cart¨ table that should have most updated information, I will have the foreign key